# What type of graphics style is used in the WP Bones website?

Tags: website-design, style, style-identification

I'm trying to design a couple of graphics and a header image for my website .

I came across the "Bones" website and really liked their style of graphics for the clouds and background sky.[image]

[The website can be viewed here](http://themble.com/bones/)

Can anyone tell me if this type of styling has a name, or any resources out there that can show how to make these kind of graphics?

Comment: There's nothing specific about it--other than 'illustration'. It's somewhat flat, somewhat geometric, somewhat vector. All are terms that *could* describe it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the style it's called. I call it "2D flat art," with a retro 20s/30s texture feel for added texture. The approach uses a limited color palette. The basic way to create this art is to use a darker color of the object's color as the shadow color. If the jacket is red, the shadow would be a darker red, with no gradients; hence, "flat".  Flash, Illustrator or Photoshop are good programs to create these styles.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so much an illustrative technique so much as it is a rendering one. These are likely Illustrator vector graphics that have had textures applied after the fact.

Creative Bloq has a nice [tutorial on adding textures to vector illustrations](http://www.creativebloq.com/graphic-design/add-depth-and-texture-illustrator-5132626).

Answer (score 0):

If you were a 'Lazy Bones' you could probably find the separate elements on a stock website - Pirate/bones/illustration and fluffy/white/clouds - make your self a blue sky background and 'Bobs your uncle'

Answer (score -3):

It seems to be a variation of Flat UI design.

Comment: Hi there! I think this got downvoted because it refers to the style of the site, when the question is asked about the style of the illustration alone (someone else referred to it as "flat art", which is quite close to your description).